# Get DISTINCT IDs for DISTINCT dates in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, distinct-values

I'm trying to get DISTINCT IDs for DISTINCT dates in BigQuery to build a report.
The date field is the kay partition field.
I tried to start with something looking like

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Id) FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE DATE(KeyPartitionDate) 
BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2020-06-01'
```

But this only gives me the different Ids between those 2 dates.
Now when it comes to query and check for every month of the year the DISTINCT(Ids), I have no clue how to do it. 
I tried using DISTINCT and GROUP By for the Date but that doesn't seem to be the right path...
Any idea ?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses, and write clearer code, i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for number of distinct IDs for each month then this might help you.

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE(KeyPartitionDate), MONTH) as month,COUNT(DISTINCT Id) as num_of_Ids 
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE DATE(KeyPartitionDate) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2020-06-01'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(DATE(KeyPartitionDate), MONTH)
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I looked for thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT
  DATE_TRUNC(DATE(KeyPartitionDate), MONTH) year_month,
  id 
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE DATE(KeyPartitionDate) 
BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2020-06-01'
```